# Accessing values in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

**Question revised for clarity:**
Im having issue parsing json file. I want to output the value of the basename labeled "image_01". So the it will only outputs `http://blog.url/news/images/201516.jpg`

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script>
var data={
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "This is The Title",
            "customFields": [
                {
                    "basename": "image_01",
                    "value": "<form mt:asset-id=\"352706\" class=\"mt-enclosure mt-enclosure-image\" style=\"display: inline;\"><a href=\"http://blog.com/news/images/20150116.jpg\">20150116.jpg</a></form>"
                }
            ],
            "permalink": "http://blog.com/index.php"
        }
    ]
}

document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.items[0].title + " " + data.items[0].permalink+"--"+ data.items[0].customFields.basename.image_01;
</script>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/v57s2csa/**
fixed

I think particular problem lies in

> data.items[0].customFields.basename.image_01;

Comment: There is a problem with your json. Check it via jsonlint online.

Comment: You're absolutely right @T.J.Crowder. It was certainly tedious for me (mandatorily) hopping over elsewhere to check out code.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's JavaScript code. And this has nothing to do with parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customFields` is an array. You need to access the values inside it with an index.

```
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.items[0].title + " " + data.items[0].permalink+"--"+ data.items[0].customFields[0].basename;
// Change is here -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v57s2csa/1/

Comment: This one is correct and you (Maca) also mentioning the value in the statement (...basename.image_01), where the statement is completely incorrect. we must stop till the name to access its corresponding name

Answer (score 0):

Replace the javascript with:

```
  document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data.items[0].title + " " 
+ data.items[0].permalink+"--"+ data.items[0].customFields[0].basename.image_01;
```

to reflect that `customFields` is `array`, not `object`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no object called image_01 inside data. Instead of

```
data.items[0].customFields.basename.image_01;
```

use

```
data.items[0].customFields[0].value
```

Also a img tag inside Form to display image after appending,

http://blog.url/news/images/201516.jpg\">`<img src='http://blog.url/news/images/201516.jpg'/>`</a></form>